# should have had the engine checked VS should have checked the engine

Tags: usage, active-vs-passive

Would you ever say *We should have checked the engine.* instead of *We should have had the engine checked.* to mean been somebody else would do the job for us?

In Russian, we mostly use active structures for such situations, for example *I need to check the engine.* or * I am going to cut my hair.* even though these are services others do for us.

Comment: "We should have checked the engine", to me, still allows the possibility of getting someone else to do it for you. At least in the UK. Of course, it also allows the possibility of the speaker personally doing the checking, which the alternative "should have *had* the engine checked" does not.

Comment: There’s something to this question, because to me “I’m going to cut my hair” definitely means cutting your own hair(not a barber), but “I never cut my hair” would include someone doing it for me. (As would “you should cut your hair”)

Comment: For me in the US, “checking the engine” means performing the checking oneself, whereas “having the engine checked” is when a trained mechanic performs it.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the statement is made in the active voice:

> He should have checked the tires.

then *he* was remiss in not checking the tires *himself*.

> He should have had the tires checked.

He was remiss in not taking the car to a garage to have the tires checked *by a mechanic*.